# How to read a column without header from csv and save the output in a txt file using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a file "TAB.csv" with many columns. I would like to choose one column without header (index of that column is 3) from CSV file. Then create a new text file "NEW.txt" and write there that column (without header).

Below code reads that column but with the header. How to omit the header and save that column in a new text file?

```
import csv
with open('TAB.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row[3]
```

Comment: Can you supply minimal input and output samples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the solution @tmrlvi was talking: it skips the first row (header) via next function:

```
import csv

with open('TAB.csv','rb') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    output_file = open('output.csv','w')
    next(reader, None)

    for row in reader:
        row_str = row[3]
        output_file.write(row_str + '\n')

    output_file.close()
```

Comment: reader=csv.reader(input_file)
    output_file = open('NEW.txt','w')

   Working well as well :) Thanks

Comment: Thank you @zone1, will fix it!!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('TAB.csv', 'rb') as f, open('out.txt', 'wb') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)            # skip header
    g.writelines(row[3] + '\n' for row in reader)
```

Answer (score 3):

`enumerate` is a nice function that returns a tuple. It enables to to view the index while running over an iterator.

```
import csv
with open('NEW.txt','wb') as outfile:
    with open('TAB.csv','rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for index, row in enumerate(reader):
           if index > 0:
               outfile.write(row[3])
               outfile.write("\n")
```

Another solution would be to read one line from the file (in order to skip the header).

Comment: Here the output is written in one line. I need to get a column of numbers, same as it was in csv filer.

Comment: if the output is written one line, replace the `'\n'` with `'\r\n'` (you're probably working in windows). You can combine it with @avenet solution which is more elegant. Anyway, this code should skip the headers. (it doesn't write the first row)

Comment: Yes,I am working on Windows and '\r\n' solution solved a problem, no headers now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but I would like to add my answer about Pandas library, I would like to say. It's better to use Pandas library for such tasks instead of writing your own code. And the simple code with Pandas will be like :

```
import pandas as pd
reader = pd.read_csv('TAB.csv', header = None)
```